# Using a method call as an argument for an established method

Tags: c#, methods, arguments

Here is the direct text from working in Unity/C# book:

> try creating a new method that takes in an int parameter and simply
> prints it out to the console.  No return type necessary.  When you've
> got that, call the method in Start, pass in a GenerateCharacter method
> call as its argument, and take a look at the output.

I've tried a few different things (declaring variable in Start, creating new method and calling it, with Debug.Log in the body), but no luck.  Not sure where to start.

```
public class LearningCurve : MonoBehaviour
{


    void Start()
    {
        int characterLevel = 32;
        

        int nextSkillLevel = GenerateCharacter("Spike", characterLevel);
        Debug.Log(nextSkillLevel);
        Debug.Log(GenerateCharacter("Faye", characterLevel));
       

    }

    public int GenerateCharacter(string name, int level)
    {
        //Debug.LogFormat("Character: {0} - Level: {1}", name, level);
        return level + 5;
        
    }
   
        
        
 }
```

Comment: _pass in a GenerateCharacter method call as its argument_ - would mean `YourMethod(GenerateCharacter("Spike", characterLevel))`

Answer (score 0):

Start at the `Action` and `Function` types in C#

[Action Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-5.0) - Use it when you don't need any return type

[Function Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-5.0) - Use it when you need a return type

(Hint) You can do this:

```
int characterLevel = 1;
Func<string,int,int> functionStoringVariable = GenerateCharacter;
// Call the function by the variable
int result = functionStoringVariable("Spike", characterLevel);
```

Comment: That code wouldn't actually compile... but I don't think the book is *actually* trying to talk about delegates anyway, given that it talks about creating a new method accepting an int parameter. But it does sound like the book is very, very far from clear...

Comment: True story! I updated the code to make it compile though.

Comment: I think @fabio's interpretation in their comment on the OP is likely the intended one

Comment: Agreed! That's why I suggested the way to get there.

Comment: I don't think you have. You're talking about delegates and method groups. Fabio's suggestion (and my interpretation) is just that the OP is being taught how to use the result of one method as the input to another. Delegates at this point are way too advanced of a topic if the OP can't figure out simple method calls

Comment: Thank you everyone, this actually helps.  It gives me a better road to consider.